# How to retrieve 5 biggest numbers in a repeated value column?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to use SQL query to find the 3 biggest numbers in a nested table.  if the count of each repeated values are less than 5, then list as many as there are.
So here is the nested table:
[image]

So I want to retrieve 3 of the largest ages for each companyID

```
select companyID,customer 
from test.table, unnest(customer) as c 
order by c.age
limit 3
```

but the Limit does not change anything I also tried to add a where clause `where c.age>25` as an example but I noticed the condition does not effect at all.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [array_agg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg):

```
select
  companyID,
  array_agg(struct(c.name, c.age) order by c.age desc limit 3)
from test.table, unnest(customer) as c
group by 1
```

Comment: Thank you Sergey, where should I really start to learn nested tables and these kind of queries? btw, I accepted your answer. Thank you

Comment: Just Google docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays

Answer (score 2):

Consider below solution (no extra group by needed)

```
select * replace (
  array(select as struct * from t.customer order by age desc limit 5) 
  as customer)
from `project.dataset.table` t
```